# XPages Guidelines when developing applications for Bluemix?

Tags: xpages, ibm-cloud

I have created an XPages application that uses the Bootstrap theme from Extension library and deployed it to Bluemix, but have noticed that the bootstrap theme does not seem to be available in Bluemix.

where can I find developer guidelines for building Domino applications in Domino Designer for deployment to Bluemix?

Answer (score 2):

ON the blog of Oliver Busse are some items about XPages in combination with Bluemix. I found this entry very helpful, because we had 2 OSGi plugins which was used by our XPages application. http://oliverbusse.notesx.net/hp.nsf/blogpost.xsp?documentId=FD2